# Is the Cirrus Vision SF50 the only civilian monojet currently on production?

Tags: jet, private-jets

Since the Piper PA-47 and Diamond D-jet never made it past prototype stage, is the Cirrus Vision the only single engine civilian turbofan jet in production?

What other monojets have made it into production?

Comment: If you include production kits, then there is also the [ViperJet MKII](http://viperjet.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/MKII-Executive-side-2.pdf) and the [Sonex SubSonex](http://www.sonexaircraft.com/subsonex/).

Comment: Are you discounting ex-military craft now on the civilian register?

Comment: @Simon Yeah. There are quite a few military mono's but I don't hear of many civilian ones.

Comment: No there was a prototype PiperJet; it just never made it past that.

Comment: "monojet" -- is that like a jet powered monorail?  Or maybe a jet-powered Moni?   ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monnett_Moni )  Or maybe a jet that is a monoplane rather than a biplane ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PZL_M-15_Belphegor ) or triplane (http ???)

Comment: He means a single engine jet airplane.  Stop nitpicking

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiple VLJ kitplanes have been on the market for several decades now; probably the most famous of which was the Bede BD-5J which gained fame in the 007 film Octopussy.  BD-5Js flew in airshows with the Coors Light Silver Bullet aerobatic team.

A supersonic VLJ kit called the Bede BD-10 was planned and flyable prototypes were produced.

And multiple companies have come and gone, offering everything from VLJ kits to wishful thoughts such as the ViperJet to MaverickJets to Stratos.

But near as I know the Cirrus SF-50 is the only certified single engine civilian aircraft for sale today.  Eclipse came close with its E-400, but it only remained a technology demonstrator.

The only other single engine jet airplanes on the market are military.  Aero Vodochody's L-29 and L-39 jet trainers are popular with civilians and air race teams as are MiG-15s -17s, -21s and even a few MiG-23s.  Western fighters like the F-86 Sabre, the Folland Gnat, the De Havilland Vampire, and the BAe Hawk are also popular.

Comment: The formerly military jets are not operated as "certified" aircraft. They get restricted experimental airworthiness certificates, usually exhibition-only.